# Java For loop Issue in condition statement

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

I am trying to find our all the prime numbers in a given array. For this, I have written following code. Somehow, it is not working as expected.
Kindly help me debug the issue.

```
public class primenbr {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        int a[]= { -2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97};

        int Prime_flag=0;
        //for loop to keep going one by one and to check if the number is prime 
        System.out.println("welcome to Basic prime number program");
        for(int j=0;j<=99 & a[j] > 1;j++) {
            Prime_flag=0;

                //checks for prime number
                for(int i=2,div=(int) Math.sqrt(a[j]) + 1; i <= div;i++){

                    if (a[j]%i==0){ 
                        Prime_flag++;                           
                    }
                }

            if ((Prime_flag == 0 & a[j] >= 2) | a[j] == 2)
                System.out.println("Hurray!!! This is a prime number"+a[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> welcome to Basic prime number program

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do you think your code should work, and why do you think so?

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of new to this forum. My question is in below code System.out.println("welcome to Basic prime number program");
        for(int j=0;j<=99 & a[j] > 1;j++)                                                                  Why it's not entering to this for loop, though I am increment value of J after every iteration.

Comment: Debug is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition to iterate your loop

```
for(int j=0; j<=99 & a[j] > 1; j++)
```

is `j<=99 & a[j]`.

You initialized `j` to `0`, so `j<=99` part is `true`, but problem lies in second part of this condition.
For `j=0` condition `a[j]>1` becomes `a[0]>1`, but `a[0]` is `-2`, which leaves us with `-2>1` which is `false`.

So we end up with `true & false` which is `false`, so your loop will no longer iterate (or to be more precise will not even start iterating).

Comment: Thanks Pshemo, I got the logic. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read up on a  [for loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm). Your first loop is initialized, then the boolean is checked. In this case, a[0]<1 since a[0] is -2. You need to change the condition to be greater than 1 or in the initialization set initialization to a.length-1.

Your first loop should look like this.

```
for(j=a.length-1;a[j] > 1 && j>=0;j--)
```

Comment: But it would be adding 1 to j in every loop and during 4th iteration it should accept the condition as a[3] = 2. However, the same condition 'a[j] > 1', if I am putting in next for loop it is accepting it and printing all the prime numbers. So, why not in first.

Comment: Beacuse a[0] <1 so, as stated, when the for loop condition is checked just after instantiation, the loop fails. Since the second loop is nested, it will not run. The document I linked to offers a detailed explanation. Also, in the second loop, if you don't need the numbers or count of divisors, then you could use a while loop. Move the instantiation out of the loop in this case. It will save some calculations.

Comment: It is accepting it in the second loop because you are running the first one until j= 99 and not checking for a[j] >1 in that case. Sorry it took a couple read throughs to get to that. You will notice that -2 through 1 are not printed out in that case.

Comment: If you wanted even more speed, you could use a prime sieve. That is what I did in my C programming class. It is extremely fast.

Comment: @Andrew  No - the "&" is the wrong operator, it should be "&&".  The OP also incorrectly uses "&" and "|" elsewhere, where "&&" and "||" should be used.

Comment: Not necisarilly && is short circuit for & which will kill the process on falsity of one variable whereas & does not terminate on false. | can be used in  place of || and terminates on true. Here that doesn't matter. See the array a.  In this case, it makes sense that j needs to be both less than 99 and greater than 1 even if the decision adds unnecessary calculations.

Comment: The Prime number print statement is just a poor programming decision since it double checks a condition.

Comment: Though yes, also in the print statement | should be & or &&

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `a[j]` is less than 1 on the first iteration, so the condition is false, and the loop is never entered.

`for(int j=0;j<=99 & a[j] > 1;j++)`

But because `j[0] == -2`, the second half of the condition is false.

Comment: Thanks I got it, I'm actually ashamed of myself that I asked this question. It's been a long time after which I started coding. Anyways, glad there are people like you to help us.

Comment: No worries. :) I am fortunate enough to be in an office full of programmers that can point out my simple mistakes. We all make them.